# Create array by date from existing array

Tags: php, arrays, json, sorting, date

I have an array of items. All items contain a start_date.

Based on the start date I want to create a new array, starting with start_date as key and then every entry for that day inside.

so from this:

(example in json, orginal array is way longer with multiple entries for every day)

```
[
        {
            "Booking_id": "135474",
            "Start_date": "2017-08-11 09:10:00",
            "End_date": "2017-08-11 09:59:00",
            "Max_participants": null,
            "Description": "Schedule Sports Hall 3",
            "Trainer": "1053",
            "Memo": null,
            "Cms_id": null,
            "Product_id": "85",
            "First_name": "Teri",
            "Middle_name": null,
            "Last_name": "Hatcher"
        },
        {
            "Booking_id": "133718",
            "Start_date": "2017-08-11 10:00:00",
            "End_date": "2017-08-11 10:59:00",
            "Max_participants": null,
            "Description": "Schedule Sports Hall 3",
            "Trainer": "1053",
            "Memo": null,
            "Cms_id": null,
            "Product_id": "85",
            "First_name": "Teri",
            "Middle_name": null,
            "Last_name": "Hatcher"
        },
        {
            "Booking_id": "135514",
            "Start_date": "2017-08-12 11:00:00",
            "End_date": "2017-08-12 11:59:00",
            "Max_participants": null,
            "Description": "Schedule Sports Hall 3",
            "Trainer": "1053",
            "Memo": null,
            "Cms_id": null,
            "Product_id": "85",
            "First_name": "Teri",
            "Middle_name": null,
                "Last_name": "Hatcher"
            }
]
```

I want to make this:

```
{
  "2017-08-11" : [ {
            "Booking_id": "135474",
            "Start_date": "2017-08-11 09:10:00",
            "End_date": "2017-08-11 09:59:00",
            "Max_participants": null,
            "Description": "Schedule Sports Hall 3",
            "Trainer": "1053",
            "Memo": null,
            "Cms_id": null,
            "Product_id": "85",
            "First_name": "Teri",
            "Middle_name": null,
            "Last_name": "Hatcher"
        },
        {
            "Booking_id": "133718",
            "Start_date": "2017-08-11 10:00:00",
            "End_date": "2017-08-11 10:59:00",
            "Max_participants": null,
            "Description": "Schedule Sports Hall 3",
            "Trainer": "1053",
            "Memo": null,
            "Cms_id": null,
            "Product_id": "85",
            "First_name": "Teri",
            "Middle_name": null,
            "Last_name": "Hatcher"
        }
],
"2017-08-12" => ,
        [{
            "Booking_id": "135514",
            "Start_date": "2017-08-12 11:00:00",
            "End_date": "2017-08-12 11:59:00",
            "Max_participants": null,
            "Description": "Schedule Sports Hall 3",
            "Trainer": "1053",
            "Memo": null,
            "Cms_id": null,
            "Product_id": "85",
            "First_name": "Teri",
            "Middle_name": null,
                "Last_name": "Hatcher"
            }]
   }
```

I'm not sure if the json are accurate but I think you get the point. I have tried this myself but found a couple of performance issues making everything taking way too long.

Comment: add your code so we can help.

Comment: @satyampathak My example code is way worse I do a while loop while end_date < $current_date and add 1 day to the loop and then execute a query to get this info per day.... 

Now I execute a query for the total days i want this is way quicker.There is no need for me to post any code. Right answer has even been posteda lready

Comment: @RoyStijsiger, I already gave you the shortest cod for this.. Please check the answer below... Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is your solutions....

```
$json = '[
    {
        "Booking_id": "135474",
        "Start_date": "2017-08-11 09:10:00",
        "End_date": "2017-08-11 09:59:00",
        "Max_participants": null,
        "Description": "Schedule Sports Hall 3",
        "Trainer": "1053",
        "Memo": null,
        "Cms_id": null,
        "Product_id": "85",
        "First_name": "Teri",
        "Middle_name": null,
        "Last_name": "Hatcher"
    },
    {
        "Booking_id": "133718",
        "Start_date": "2017-08-11 10:00:00",
        "End_date": "2017-08-11 10:59:00",
        "Max_participants": null,
        "Description": "Schedule Sports Hall 3",
        "Trainer": "1053",
        "Memo": null,
        "Cms_id": null,
        "Product_id": "85",
        "First_name": "Teri",
        "Middle_name": null,
        "Last_name": "Hatcher"
    },
    {
        "Booking_id": "135514",
        "Start_date": "2017-08-12 11:00:00",
        "End_date": "2017-08-12 11:59:00",
        "Max_participants": null,
        "Description": "Schedule Sports Hall 3",
        "Trainer": "1053",
        "Memo": null,
        "Cms_id": null,
        "Product_id": "85",
        "First_name": "Teri",
        "Middle_name": null,
            "Last_name": "Hatcher"
        }
]';

$array = json_decode($json,true);
$new = array();
foreach($array as $row){
    $new[date('Y-m-d',strtotime($row['Start_date']))][] = $row; 
}
echo '<pre>'; print_r($new);
```

$new contains the array which you want...